# facebook notification return (#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."

Tags: facebook, api, notifications

I'm trying to send a facebook notification from my app, but actually the Graph API Explorer is still returning me "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."

This is what I do:

```
1000000001/notifications?access_token=100000000000001|Quuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuw&href=http://www.xxx.com/&template=Hello
```

although I take the app access token in the several ways, and I already use this token to delete app request.

```
$APPLICATION_ID = "APP_ID";
$APPLICATION_SECRET = "APP_SECRET";

$token_url =    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
        "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID .
        "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET .
        "&grant_type=client_credentials";
$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

or 
     `access_token = YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_SECRET`.

I know that App Access Token doesn't expires.

This solution doesn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12771192/1022298

Edit. App_id and secret are invented.