# Facebook Graph API Notifcations POST Doesn't Work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to Post notification to a user using the graph api, and I get this error:

> "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."

But I'm using an app access token for sure. Got it from -

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials

(See picture attached)
http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/6486/h6zs.png

I was looking for help but didn't find anything that solve the problem
. This thread did not help: [Facebook notifications API: "This method must be called with an app access_token"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771078/facebook-notifications-api-this-method-must-be-called-with-an-app-access-token/12771192#12771192)

Can anyone tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use the user-access token while making the call. (Since you can set the `access token` parameter only once, i.e. the App's token)
2. Since you are not using the user's token, use the `user id` instead of `me` while making the call. `/ID/notifications`

Comment: Still gets;code: 15
message: "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."
type: "OAuthException"

Comment: It's not possible. Can you post the screenshot? (As you posted in the question)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the access token from here :

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

I had the same problem, and I've solved like that.